# Why GSM/GPRS SIM800Lmodule is not working in England,UK

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, gsm, gprs, sim800

I am from England and I am using SIM800L Module for sending the SMS. My module is not connecting with the network(LED blinks every second instead of after 3 seconds). I don't know what's the issue, I wanna know whether this module (SIM800L) works in England or not? If not then whats the other 4G supported module that will work fine? I am using Raspberry Pi 3 for interfacing GPRS module.